# R download.file to a folder keeping original name

Tags: r, r-download.file

I'm trying to download a single file with a GET request URL that doesn't specify the filename of the returned file. It returns zip files if you request multiple filter items, but single xlsx files if you only have one filter item. I want to download the file into a folder then find out its name, rather than save it into a tempfile with a random name.

```
# web GET request
web <- "https://www.find-school-performance-data.service.gov.uk/download-data?download=true&regions=0&filters=GIAS&fileformat=xls&year=2021-2022&meta=false"

tf <- tempfile()
td <- tempdir()

# this works fine, but gives the file a random name
download.file(web, tf, mode="wb")

#these don't work as it wants me to give the full file name, not just the folder
download.file(web, td, mode="wb")
download.file(web, paste0(td,"\\"), mode="wb")

Warning messages:
1: In download.file(web, paste0(td, "\\"), mode = "wb") :
  URL https://www.find-school-performance-data.service.gov.uk/download-data?download=true&regions=0&filters=GIAS&fileformat=xls&year=2021-2022&meta=false: cannot open destfile 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWi98JC\', reason 'No such file or directory'
2: In download.file(web, paste0(td, "\\"), mode = "wb") :
  download had nonzero exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `httr` we can fetch the name of the file being returned. This means a double GET request, but it works

```
library(httr)

td <- tempdir()
web <- "https://www.find-school-performance-data.service.gov.uk/download-data?download=true&regions=0&filters=GIAS&fileformat=xls&year=2021-2022&meta=false"

# load header response from web GET request
hdr <- HEAD(web)
filename <- gsub(".*name=", "", headers(hdr)$`content-disposition`)
```

> filename [1] "2021-2022%2Fengland_school_information.xlsx"

```
# download to temp directory using original name
download.file(web, paste0(td,"\\",filename), mode="wb")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can do this with R, but if you paste the link into your browser address bar it'll save it in a folder with a file name.
2021-2022_england_school_information.xlsx

Comment: thanks, what I'm really interested in is R telling me `2021-2022_england_school_information.xlsx` if I give it the URL. I have quite a few of these requests to run

Comment: Yeah I get what you're trying to do, I only mentioned it because I thought it might prompt some further ideas for you.  For my part, I wonder how the browser knows the filename before it downloads it?  I notice that wget doesn't know how to interpret the file name though.  Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: do you have a wget example I could work from?

Comment: wget is a linux command line tool to grab files from the web.  But it doesn't interpret the file name for the link you provided, it just saves it as ‘download-data?download=true&regions=0&filters=GIAS&fileformat=xls&year=2021-2022&meta=false’
If you're running linux you could use a system call to run wget, but I'm not sure it'll help you.

Comment: found it, searching for wget on windows led me to an httr solution.