# Download.file keeping original name or sheet name

Tags: r, web-scraping, r-xlsx, r-download.file

I want to download the following link in R keeping the file name after browser download.
[`http://www.coingecko.com/price_charts/export/1/usd.xls`](http://www.coingecko.com/price_charts/export/1/usd.xls)

Notice that the file name will be 'btc-usd-max.xls' if you download the file through browser. However, if I run the following code, the file name will be 'usd.xls'. However, the file name 'btc-usd-max.xls' conveys relevant information. Is it possible to retrieve this 'btc-usd-max' name using R?

```
link <- 'http://www.coingecko.com/price_charts/export/1/usd.xls'
download.file(url=link, destfile=basename(link), method='auto')
```

The solution provided in the following topic does not solve the problem.
[R download.file to a folder keeping original name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74559779/r-download-file-to-a-folder-keeping-original-name)

The aforementioned solution depends on `content-disposition`, which does not exists.

```
library(httr)
hd <- HEAD(link)
filename <- gsub(".*name=", "", headers(hd)$`content-disposition`)
```

I have tried using HEAD() command from httr package and also downloading the files using the download.file function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayed file name is in a response header called `content-disposition`, but only if you get a status 200 from the server. The default user-agent in httr causes the server to return a status 403 that does not return this header, so you need to add a user agent that the server will respond to.

Once this is done it's fairly easy to extract the file name.

```r
library(httr)

url <- 'http://www.coingecko.com/price_charts/export/1/usd.xls'
UA <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0"
res <- GET(url, user_agent(UA))
filename <- strsplit(res$headers$`content-disposition`, '\"')[[1]][2]
```

Now we have

```r
filename
#> [1] "btc-usd-max.xls"
```

And we can write the result like this:

```r
writeBin(res$content, filename)
```

Strangely enough though, the actual binary data appears to be in csv format rather than xls format (I get a warning when I try to open it in Excel, whether downloading in R or directly in the browser). You might prefer to read it as a csv using:

```r
data <- read.csv(text = content(res, 'text'))
```

Then write `data` to an Excel sheet named according to the filename.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, when I reproduce the code, I get the 403 status code from GET, not 200. Apparently it is behind a Cloudflare protection. Any ideas?

Comment: That's what I got before I added the user agent string @ffsffs . Did you copy-paste the code?

Comment: Yes. I've tried other generic user agent strings with the same result.

Comment: Oddly enough the code worked after I ran it in another notebook (same network, newer Windows version).